# Maven class creation missing some class

Tags: java, maven

I got some weird issue regarding class generation in Maven.
Somehow some of my class is not generated by Maven.

```
I got an abstract class "A" -> Generated
I got another abstract class "B" extends "A" -> Not generated
I got another class extends "B" -> Not generated
```

Is it possible because there is no usage then maven not creating the class?
How to make maven create the class in build?

Anyone know the reason of this? I already tried using mvn package and mvn install.

Note : There is no exclusion for the class in my pom

Comment: Please share your pom file. Also try mvn clean install.

Comment: I can't really share my pom. But the problem that I see is, the class is not generated if it is not used. I just put C c; in one of my class then its generated correctly. It's really weird, I can't deploy it since I used that class in Map<key,"A"> and I inject it in my spring xml. Is there any settings that can make that? Note: I already tried using manual mvn clean install from my cmd promt and from my IDE

Answer (score 0):

Class files are generated from all Java files in `src/main/java`. If some of the Java Files are not compiled,

- the Java files are not in `src/main/java`.
- or the source directory was changed.
- or there is some weird configuration in the pom.

Comment: No, all my abstract class "A" and "B" is in same package.
The other class that extend "B" is also in that same package too..

I actually able to build correctly before, then I change some code ( no change in pom ) then somehow the class is not generated. I am really confused on why this happened.

Comment: no error at all.. The WAR file created correctly. Other old code class also created. All that not created is all my newly created classes (except the most high parent abstract class).

Comment: Also this might be related... I actually can make the class created but I need to have the Class "C" to be used in at least one class. But this is also weird since previously it created correctly even no class using it ( I used this in the map<key,"A"> of my spring injection ) That's why I wondering if maven didnt create unused class?

Comment: This is really strange. Maven builds all the classes, not just those which are "used". I guess you are missing something, or your IDE or project structure is really broken.

Comment: yes that's why I am really stressed out here not sure why this happened. Is there any configuration that can make this happened? I never change the pom, and a couple hours ago this actually run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the issue... caused by my stupid mistake of not putting the packages name correctly in includes section of my pom.

I keep checking excludes section instead of includes section. But this is good info for me since I just know if I have includes section and I didn't put it in there then mvn won't build it, but mvn will build it if I used the class somewhere.

Thank you for the help that make me keep checking the pom.